# stop NSData loading from server

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I have the following method, which basically loads an array of image data into an array:

```
-(void)loadImages:(NSMutableArray*)imagesURLS{
    //_indexOfLastImageLoaded = 0;
    [_loadedImages removeAllObjects];
    _loadedImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
        for (int i=0; i<imagesURLS.count;i++){
            NSLog(@"loading image for main image holder at index %i",i);
            NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[imagesURLS objectAtIndex:i]];
            UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
            [_loadedImages addObject:img];
            //_indexOfLastImageLoaded++;
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"_loadedImages download COMPLETE");                      
        });
    });

}
```

I want to be able to stop it when, for example, a user moves away from the view controller that these images are being loaded in. What is the best way to do so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't cancel `NSData dataWithContentsOfUrl:`. The best way to achieve cancelable, asynchronous downloading is by using `NSURLConnection` and the `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate`.

You set up an NSMutableData object to accumulate all the data as it comes in in chunks. Then when all the data has arrived, you create your image and use it.

.h

```
@interface ImageDownloader : NSObject <NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURLConnection *theConnection;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableData *buffer;
@end
```

.m

```
-(void)startDownload
{
    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://example.com/largeImage.jpg"];
    NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: imageURL];
    _theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest: theRequest delegate: self startImmediately: YES];
}

-(void)cancelDownload
{
    // CANCELS DOWNLOAD
    // THROW AWAY DATA
    [self.theConnection cancel];
    self.buffer = nil;
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    // INITIALIZE THE DOWNLOAD BUFFER
    _buffer = [NSMutableData data];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    // APPEND DATA TO BUFFER
    [self.buffer appendData: data];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
     // DONE DOWNLOADING
    // CREATE IMAGE WITH DATA
    UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageWithData: self.buffer];
}
```

Comment: would this still work if i am using that function to load images from the array, even before it finishes downloading all images? for example, if a user tries to load an image of index 3 and the data array count is > 3, it will load the image from data, if not, it will load it from a url. From your description it seems like this class will only let me load images from data once all the data has arrived.

Comment: You would use one `NSURLConnection` object per photo to download. You could keep several instances of this class in a download manager/controller. You could also embed this functionality in an NSOperation subclass. See more at [objc.io](http://www.objc.io/issue-2/common-background-practices.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be more flexible with cancel request i advice you to use NSOperationQueue instead of pushing all request in a row.

```
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [queue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];
    for (int i=0; i<allImagesCount; i++) {
        [queue addOperationWithBlock:^{
            // load image
        }];
    }

    // for canceling operations
    [queue cancelAllOperations];
```

In you current code you can also define static field and check in for loop, but the best way will be using SDWebImage - https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage for loading image asynch.

Comment: Why set the operation count to 1? Wouldn't that reduce the concurrency advantage dramatically?

Comment: it is just example, it depends on device and counter of cores, like for ipad 3 as i remember you can set it to 4, but for ipad 2 only for 2. So it is up to you and depends on situation on main thread.

Comment: would i be able to use NSData dataWithContentsOfUrl: as an operation within the queue?